# Spherical Mercator to Cylinder mercator?

Tags: google-maps, coordinate-system, spherical-geometry

I want to create an overlay for google maps.

As far as I know google maps using Spherical Mercator, so the system where I read the maps use Mercator but is not specified which (spherical or cylinder) type it use.

When i create the images, i get some information in common. That means I have an offset. I want to try to solve this using cylinder mercator coordinates, but how can I transform google coordinates to Cylinder Mercator coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you mean Spherical vs Elliposidal Mercator. Google use real WGS84 coordinates and map them as if they were on a sphere rather then an ellipsoidal datum.
It depend on the coordinates of your original images how to reproject them on Spherical Mercator projection.
You can user [gdal_transform](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) or whatelse GIS tool to do the transformation. The target CRS is [EPSG:3857](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3785/) (or the legacy, not standard, EPSG:900913).